# How to make increase/Decrease the UpVote/DownVote like stackOverFlow?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, iosdeployment

I have this code which allows the users to make upvote or downvote like stack overflow. My problem is that the `Text("\(likes) UpVote").padding(.top, 8)`
 does not refresh immediately, instead the user should change the perspective to get the refreshed upvote/downvote.
How to improve that, so that the user can only click one time on one of them and it Changes them immediately?

This is how my code looks like:

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import Firebase

struct PostCellCard : View {

    var user = ""
    var image = ""
    var id = ""
    var likes = ""
    var comments = ""
    var msg = ""
    var body : some View{

        VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {

            HStack{

                Image("person-icon-1675").resizable().frame(width: 35, height: 35).clipShape(Circle()).onTapGesture {
                    print("slide out menu ....")
                }
                HStack(alignment: .top){
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(user).fontWeight(.heavy)
                        Text(msg).padding(.top, 8)
                    }}
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {

                }) {

                    Image("menu").resizable().frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }.foregroundColor(Color("darkAndWhite"))
            }
            if self.image != ""{
                AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: image)).resizable().frame(height: 250)
            }
            HStack{

                Button(action: {

                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    let like = Int.init(self.likes)!
                    db.collection("posts").document(self.id).updateData(["likes": "\(like - 1)"]) { (err) in

                        if err != nil{

                            print((err)!)
                            return
                        }

                        print("down updated....")
                    }

                }) {


                    Image(systemName: "arrow.down.to.line.alt").resizable().frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                }.foregroundColor(Color("darkAndWhite"))

                Button(action: {

                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    let like = Int.init(self.likes)!

                    db.collection("posts").document(self.id).updateData(["likes": "\(like + 1)"]) { (err) in
                        if err != nil{
                            print((err)!)
                            return
                        }

                        print("up updated....")
                    }

                }) {

                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.to.line.alt").resizable().frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                }.foregroundColor(Color("darkAndWhite"))

                Spacer()

            }.padding(.top, 8)

            Text("\(likes) UpVote").padding(.top, 8)
            Text("\(likes) DownVote").padding(.top, 8)
            Text("View all \(comments) Comments")


        }).padding(8)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately i had to change a lot so that it was running ...so here is my code and it works - changes likes - of course you can make an int out of it and increase it instead of just setting a text

```
struct ContentView : View {

    var user = ""
    var image = ""
    var id = ""
    @State var likes = ""
    var comments = ""
    var msg = ""
    var body : some View{
        VStack {

            HStack{

                Image(systemName:"circle").resizable().frame(width: 35, height: 35).clipShape(Circle()).onTapGesture {
                    print("slide out menu ....")
                    self.likes = "tapped"
                }
                HStack(alignment: .top){
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(user).fontWeight(.heavy)
                        Text(msg).padding(.top, 8)
                    }}
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.likes = "aha"
                }) {

                    Image(systemName:"circle").resizable().frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }.foregroundColor(Color("darkAndWhite"))
            }
            if self.image != ""{
                Text("Animated Image")
                //   AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: image)).resizable().frame(height: 250)
            }
            HStack{

                Button(action: {

                    self.likes = "oho"
                    print("button action")
                }) {

                    Image(systemName: "circle").resizable().frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                }.foregroundColor(Color("darkAndWhite"))

                Button(action: {

                    let like = Int.init(self.likes)!
                    print("action")
                    self.likes = "uhu"
                }) {
                    Text("aha")
//                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.to.line.alt").resizable().frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                }.foregroundColor(Color("darkAndWhite"))

                Spacer()

            }.padding(.top, 8)

            Text("\(likes) UpVote").padding(.top, 8)
            Text("\(likes) DownVote").padding(.top, 8)
            Text("View all \(comments) Comments")

        }.padding(8)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a property wrappers for your `likes` variable, so when you change the amount of likes, it will also change it on the Text as will.

What should work in your case is the `@State` property wrapper, which would look like this...

```
@State var likes = ""
```

For more information about property wrappers here's a good article explains them
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/understanding-property-wrappers-in-swift-and-swiftui

Comment: This does not helped